# Linking freeglut with Qt Creator in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt-creator, linker-errors, freeglut

I currently run Arch Linux on my laptop and was hoping to know why Qt Creator isn't finding my glut library (which exists on my system).

My setup qmake file looks as follows:

```
     ...
    /*sources and headers above*/

    QT += opengl

    LIBS += -lfreeglut

    INCLUDEPATH += -L/usr/lib/
```

And when I run a locate `glut`, I get the following:

```
/usr/include/kwinglutils.h
/usr/include/kwinglutils_funcs.h
/usr/include/GL/freeglut.h
/usr/include/GL/freeglut_ext.h
/usr/include/GL/freeglut_std.h
/usr/include/GL/glut.h
/usr/lib/libglut.a
/usr/lib/libglut.so
/usr/lib/libglut.so.3
/usr/lib/libglut.so.3.9.0
/usr/share/avogadro/fragments/amino_acids/D-glutamic_acid.cml
/usr/share/avogadro/fragments/amino_acids/D-glutamine.cml
/usr/share/avogadro/fragments/amino_acids/L-glutamic_acid.cml                                                                                                               
/usr/share/avogadro/fragments/amino_acids/L-glutamine.cml
/usr/share/licenses/freeglut
/usr/share/licenses/freeglut/LICENSE
/var/lib/pacman/local/freeglut-2.6.0-1
/var/lib/pacman/local/freeglut-2.6.0-1/changelog
/var/lib/pacman/local/freeglut-2.6.0-1/desc
/var/lib/pacman/local/freeglut-2.6.0-1/files
```

Note that I have tried `-lglut32` in my qmake file as well.

What could I be missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you specify `-lfoobar` in your .pro file (or with gcc in general), you're directing the compiler to search for the library `libfoobar.a`. Judging from your locate output it looks like you want:

```
LIBS += -lglut
```

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that hah.

Comment: It happens :). For future reference, INCLUDEPATH is technically for header files;  "-L" and "-l" clauses should both go under LIBS. http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs

Answer (score 1):

Oh, silly me. I just realized that the correct lib to add was just `-lglut` and not `-lglut32`. This is because there exists `libglut.so`, and not `libglut32.so`.